# Setup a project as startup, how to do it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have 2 solution projects developed with WPF. The first one is called "Software 2013" and second one "Software 2014".

I would like to give the the user the freedom to choose which version to use. So I want 2 radio buttons and the user should choose the software to use. I don't know how to do this though, so what code is needed and how to setup the project chosen by the user  as startup?

Do you have any suggestion about this solution?

Comment: Hmmm.. wouldn't it be easier if they are both installed on the user's pc and you have 2 separate shortcuts, one for Software 2013 and another for Software 2014??

Comment: @failedprogramming thanks for your feedback, i tried to do that way but not luck ,i can not install both as i changed AsseblyName and the software name ...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the projects are deployed. You can either load a certain version of an assembly based on the choice, or otherwise you could create a console app which in turn executes the appropriate solution.

Comment: Thanks ,those are the same software just change the database in remote where retrieve the data ...

Comment: That's even easier. You can have two connection strings and simply use the one you need based on the user's response.